# Update package perl-*

Tags: perl, upgrade, repository, oracle-linux

I have a linux machine Oracle Linux Server 8.7 with kernel 5.4.17-2136.317.5.3.el8uek.x86_64.

Using the **yum check-update** command, I noticed that there are a number of perl-packages that I can't update.

```
perl-Algorithm-Diff.src                                                                   1.1903-10.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                ol8_appstream
perl-Archive-Tar.src                                                                      2.38-3.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                   ol8_appstream
perl-Archive-Zip.src                                                                      1.68-3.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                   ol8_appstream
perl-CPAN.src                                                                             2.28-5.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                   ol8_appstream
perl-CPAN-Meta.src                                                                        2.150010-397.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                             ol8_appstream
perl-CPAN-Meta-Requirements.src                                                           2.140-397.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                ol8_appstream
perl-CPAN-Meta-YAML.src                                                                   0.018-1001.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                               ol8_appstream
perl-Carp.src                                                                             1.50-439.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                 ol8_appstream
perl-Config-Perl-V.src                                                                    0.32-441.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                 ol8_appstream
perl-Data-OptList.src                                                                     0.110-7.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                  ol8_appstream
perl-Data-Section.src                                                                     0.200007-8.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                               ol8_appstream
perl-Digest.src                                                                           1.20-1.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                   ol8_appstream
perl-Env.src                                                                              1.04-396.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                 ol8_appstream
perl-Exporter.src                                                                         5.74-458.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                 ol8_appstream
perl-ExtUtils-CBuilder.src                                                                1:0.280236-1.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                             ol8_appstream
perl-ExtUtils-Install.src                                                                 2.20-1.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                   ol8_appstream
perl-ExtUtils-MakeMaker.src                                                               2:7.46-3.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                 ol8_appstream
perl-ExtUtils-Manifest.src                                                                1:1.73-1.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                 ol8_appstream
perl-ExtUtils-ParseXS.src                                                                 1:3.40-439.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                               ol8_appstream
perl-File-Fetch.src                                                                       1.00-1.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                   ol8_appstream
perl-File-HomeDir.src                                                                     1.004-6.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                  ol8_appstream
perl-File-Path.src                                                                        2.16-439.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                 ol8_appstream
perl-File-Temp.src                                                                        1:0.231.100-1.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                            ol8_appstream
perl-File-Which.src                                                                       1.23-4.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                   ol8_appstream
perl-Filter-Simple.src                                                                    0.96-457.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                 ol8_appstream
perl-Getopt-Long.src                                                                      1:2.52-1.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                 ol8_appstream
perl-HTTP-Tiny.src                                                                        0.078-1.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                  ol8_appstream
perl-IO-Compress.src                                                                      2.096-1.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                  ol8_appstream
perl-IO-Socket-IP.src                                                                     0.41-2.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                   ol8_appstream
perl-IPC-Cmd.src                                                                          2:1.04-2.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                 ol8_appstream
perl-IPC-System-Simple.src                                                                1.30-3.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                   ol8_appstream
perl-JSON-PP.src                                                                          1:4.04-2.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                 ol8_appstream
perl-Locale-Maketext.src                                                                  1.29-440.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                 ol8_appstream
perl-MRO-Compat.src                                                                       0.13-5.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                   ol8_appstream
perl-Math-BigInt.src                                                                      1:1.9998.18-1.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                            ol8_appstream
perl-Math-BigRat.src                                                                      0.2614-2.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                 ol8_appstream
perl-Module-Build.src                                                                     2:0.42.31-5.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                              ol8_appstream
perl-Module-CoreList.src                                                                  1:5.20211020-1.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                           ol8_appstream
perl-Module-Load.src                                                                      1:0.36-1.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                 ol8_appstream
perl-Module-Load-Conditional.src                                                          0.74-1.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                   ol8_appstream
perl-Module-Metadata.src                                                                  1.000037-1.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                               ol8_appstream
perl-Package-Generator.src                                                                1.106-12.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                 ol8_appstream
perl-Params-Check.src                                                                     1:0.38-396.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                               ol8_appstream
perl-Perl-OSType.src                                                                      1.010-397.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                ol8_appstream
perl-PerlIO-via-QuotedPrint.src                                                           0.09-1.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                   ol8_appstream
perl-Pod-Checker.src                                                                      4:1.74-1.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                 ol8_appstream
perl-Pod-Escapes.src                                                                      1:1.07-396.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                               ol8_appstream
perl-Pod-Parser.src                                                                       1.63-1001.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                ol8_appstream
perl-Pod-Perldoc.src                                                                      3.28.01-443.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                              ol8_appstream
perl-Pod-Simple.src                                                                       1:3.42-1.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                 ol8_appstream
perl-Pod-Usage.src                                                                        4:2.01-1.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                 ol8_appstream
perl-Software-License.src                                                                 0.103014-5.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                               ol8_appstream
perl-Sub-Exporter.src                                                                     0.987-17.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                 ol8_appstream
perl-Sub-Install.src                                                                      0.928-15.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                 ol8_appstream
perl-Term-ANSIColor.src                                                                   5.01-458.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                 ol8_appstream
perl-Term-Cap.src                                                                         1.17-396.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                 ol8_appstream
perl-Test-Harness.src                                                                     1:3.42-2.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                 ol8_appstream
perl-Test-Simple.src                                                                      3:1.302181-2.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                             ol8_appstream
perl-Text-Balanced.src                                                                    2.04-1.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                   ol8_appstream
perl-Text-Diff.src                                                                        1.45-7.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                   ol8_appstream
perl-Text-Glob.src                                                                        0.11-5.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                   ol8_appstream
perl-Text-ParseWords.src                                                                  3.30-396.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                 ol8_appstream
perl-Text-Tabs+Wrap.src                                                                   2013.0523-396.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                            ol8_appstream
perl-Text-Template.src                                                                    1.58-1.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                   ol8_appstream
perl-Thread-Queue.src                                                                     3.14-457.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                 ol8_appstream
perl-Time-Local.src                                                                       2:1.300-4.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                ol8_appstream
perl-URI.src                                                                              1.76-5.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                   ol8_appstream
perl-autodie.src                                                                          2.34-1.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                   ol8_appstream
perl-bignum.src                                                                           0.51-439.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                 ol8_appstream
perl-constant.src                                                                         1.33-1001.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                ol8_appstream
perl-experimental.src                                                                     0.025-1.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                  ol8_appstream
perl-inc-latest.src                                                                       2:0.500-10.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                               ol8_appstream
perl-libnet.src                                                                           3.13-1.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                                   ol8_appstream
perl-local-lib.src                                                                        2.000024-7.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                               ol8_appstream
perl-parent.src                                                                           1:0.238-457.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                              ol8_appstream
perl-perlfaq.src                                                                          5.20210520-1.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                             ol8_appstream
perl-podlators.src                                                                        1:4.14-457.module+el8.6.0+20545+312b6629                                                               ol8_appstream
```

When I try **yum update**, it does not show those packages, but if I try to update single package it gives me this:

```
root@rhel1 [~] 10:55 0 #: yum update perl-Algorithm-Diff.src
Last metadata expiration check: 1:16:31 ago on Thu 30 Mar 2023 09:38:02 AM CEST.
Package perl-Algorithm-Diff.src available, but installed for different architecture.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

On the repository of **oracle-linux-ol8.repo**, is activated:

```
[ol8_appstream]
name=Oracle Linux 8 Application Stream ($basearch)
baseurl=https://yum$ociregion.$ocidomain/repo/OracleLinux/OL8/appstream/$basearch/
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
```

I saw this [post](https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/dnf-check-update-perl-modules-5013) , has a solution been found?

Some advice?

Comment: As per the posting you linked, _"This is a known issue with our repo as we have both the binary and source RPMs in the same place. "_ and _"We are working on this and will be splitting the source RPMs out into their own repo, but I don't have an ETA for this."_. Considering the poster identifies as Oracle employee, wouldn't that forum be a more appropriate place to ask for an update?

Comment: Hi @Peregrino69 , that post is dated 2021 and I didn't find any news, I was hoping to find some kind person who found/knew something about it. Thanks anyway.